# MIPS using different register types but same solution wise

Tags: assembly, mips

I am wondering is there any difference when you use different register such as the code below:

Here the correct answer uses register `$v0` all the way:

```
get_status:
        lui $t0,0xabab
        ori $t0, $t0, 0x0020

        lw $v0,0($t0)
        andi $v0,$v0,0x4
        srl $v0,$v0,2

        jr $ra
```

I used `$t1` instead of `$v0` above, notice I have a extra `sw`:

```
get_status:
        lui $t0,0xabab
        ori $t0, $t0, 0x0020

        lw $t1,0($t0)
        andi $t1,$t1,0x4
        srl $t1,$t1,2
        sw $t1, 0($t0)

        jr $ra
```

I think both code works the same, what you guys think?

Comment: Standard calling convention expects return value in `$v0`. You don't have to use `$v0` all the way, but should make sure the result is in there when returning. Also, as you pointed out, you have an extra `sw` so that would overwrite data in memory while the first version doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$v0` and `$t1` are both call-clobbered general-purpose integer registers.  They're not "different types".

But in the standard MIPS calling convention, `$v0` (and sometimes `$v1`) is where callers expect to find integer return values.  That's why `get_status` calculates a result in `$v0`.

> I think both code works the same, what you guys think?

Your code modifies the static storage that it loaded from!!!  It's not a `get_status` anymore.

It's either `void update_status(void)` or `int update_status(void)` with a non-standard calling convention (returning in `$t1`).

---

This is inefficient:

```
lui ...
ori $t0, $t0, 0x0020
lw  $v0,0($t0)
```

Use the immediate offset space of `lw` to hold the low 16 bits of the static address.  (It's sign extended, vs. `ori` zero-extending its immediate, but in this case you don't need to adjust the `lui` because the offset is signed positive.)

```
lui ...
lw  $v0, 0x0020($t0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination, just to wrap it up from my perspective, `$v0` is actually used for method suchs as like `int update_status()` that returns a value. `$t0` is probably used for void methods, did I get it correctly?

Comment: @nihulus: In a `void` function, `$v0` and `$v1` are basically just extra `$t` registers: call-clobbered regs that have no meaning to your caller.